# Why my App's Dll is not loading in win2000 and loading in XP

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc, installshield, windows-server-2000

We have an installer application. 
In that we have one dll related to our application.
We created setup with all respective files.
We used "Install Shield 6.3" and created a setup file.
After created build. The build is working in xp, not working in 2000.

It is showing error message as Couldn't load .dll only in win2000.

What could be the issue any idea?
Regards
Hara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running installation with [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) in the background, filtering with the missing DLL's name. Then, see where the DLL is searched for, and fix the problem. Hard to say without any further information, but first difference I have in mind is that the system folder in XP is C:\windows\system32, while in win2000 it is C:\winnt\system32. If you've hardcoded the system path for any reason, it might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this point is really helpful. This point i know but it really did not struck to my mind. Cheers. :)
Regards
haranadh

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of the system/third party dll you are loading is either not available or of wrong version. Use a tool like [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check whether all the required dlls are available or not.

Answer (score 2):

You have probbely missing prequsits that exits on XP but not on Win2000.
You need to run the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool on Win2000 and load the problematic DLL, the tool will tell what is missing.